# get distinct value with last row value of other column

Tags: mysql

if my databse table is like::

```
id name  
1  Mani  
1  Manish  
2  mani  
2  manish  
3  abcd  
4  efgh
```

now i want to lik::

> ```
> id name  
> 1  Manish  
> 2  manish  
> 3  abcd  
> 4  efgh
> ```

(I need to distinct value of id and last row value of name by sql query)

Comment: There is no "last value". There is no order in a set, you'll have to give us more information on what you want to select.

Comment: Are the strings supposed to be ordered in any way?  Like alphabetical by ID?  Where the last name is always last alphabetically?

Comment: @Mr.Vincent Savard:here last-value mean last row value.(when you apply distinct on id)

Comment: @roberttdev:: doesn't matter it.

Comment: @Vincent Savard is right. How you decided wich of the values selected? why the last row and not first row?

Comment: @Manish Trivedi: I'm sure we all understand what you want, but the problem is that in SQL, there is no last row or first row. For instance, in your case, your RDBMS showed Mani to appear before Manish, but it could have been the opposite. There is no way to tell which one is the first or the last, we need more information to make a choice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, MAX(name) name
from YourTable
group by id
```

IF that´s doesn't matter it.